# Proper ES6 Import Indentation

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

How should I properly indent a very large es6 import statement?
Is there any best practice/styleguide for this?

```
import { checkOldPassword, changeAddress, insertAddress, deleteAddress, changeEmail, changePassword, getCountries } from '../../actions/userActions.js'
```

I've researched through the AirBnb styleguide for react but it doen't seem to address the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally always use trailing commas, just like I would for multiline objects, arrays, and for destructuring, e.g.

```
import { 
    checkOldPassword, 
    changeAddress, 
    insertAddress, 
    deleteAddress, 
    changeEmail, 
    changePassword, 
    getCountries,
} from '../../actions/userActions.js';
```

This is also the format defined [in the AirBnB style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#modules--multiline-imports-over-newlines) .

Comment: Accepted because you provided the reference to the style guide ;) Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: do you really want a comma after `getCountries`?

Comment: @Sulthan Some style guides like airbnb recommend it because it leads to cleaner `git` diffs, like if you wanted to add a new import. It's not a big deal either way.

Comment: @saadq Thanks, now I understand the reasoning. I actually thought that trailing commas were illegal but apparently that's not the case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's illegal in `JSON`, but JavaScript allows it.

Comment: JS has been moving more and more toward allowing trailing commas. Trailing commas for objects and arrays have been allowed since ES5, ES6's names module list also allows them, and ES8 will include trailing commas for function calls and parameter lists.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing all in one line, you can use new line for each, like this:

```
import { 
    checkOldPassword, 
    changeAddress, 
    insertAddress, 
    deleteAddress, 
    changeEmail, 
    changePassword, 
    getCountries } from '../../actions/userActions.js';
```

[Check this](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#modules--multiline-imports-over-newlines).

I think this is what you want, let me know if it doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer "elm style" of indenting for such situations:

```
import { checkOldPassword
    , changeAddress
    , insertAddress, 
    , deleteAddress
    , changeEmail
    , changePassword 
    , getCountries 
} from '../../actions/userActions.js'
```

It may seem weird on a first look but what is cool - it allows to add/remove imported properties with editor's *add row* / *remove row* command. I'm a Vim user and found this really convenient.

Comment: Not really, it just moves the one missing comma from the end to the beginning.